# how to split the one column data into number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Table-1**

```
create table test (dname varchar(250))
insert test values('0.1 ML LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE 10 MG/ML')
select * from test

                  dname
                 -------

0.1 ML LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE 10 MG/ML
```

i have one more table like

**Table-2**

```
create table test1(
unit1 int,
measure1 varchar(20),
drugname varchar(250),
unit2 int,
measure2 varchar(40)
)
```

now i have to inset the data from test table to test1 table by using insert into newtablename select from old table name

my expected output is

```
select * from test1

unit1     measure1     drugname                    unit2      measure2
0.1       ML           LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE     10           mg/ml
```

kindly note that here drug name length i.e `LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE` may increase or decrease.
I observed so many questions posted here that are not suitable to my requirements.

Please provide solution to this problem.

Don't give any suggestions as already simpler problem is there. Because already I referred the question and answers posted in this site.

Comment: If it's **only** drugname that really has a variable length *(we can't tell from the table definition)*, it is doable but if the other columns have variable length and more importantly, variable amount of words, I doubt there will be an easy way to do it.

Comment: may be i have no idea , and dname datatype is nvarchar(400),kindly have a look on it if u get any idea , share it with me

Comment: Agree with Lieven, I think you need think about process it forehead, I mean where did you get the data in first table? That should not be the  original format isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/515b5/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (dname varchar(250))
insert test values('0.1 ML LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE 10 MG/ML')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select left(dname, S1.Pos - 1) as FirstWord,
       substring(dname, S1.Pos + 1, S2.Pos - S1.Pos - 1) as SecondWord,
       substring(dname, S2.Pos+1, len(dname)-S3.Pos-S2.Pos) as WordsInTheMiddle,
       left(right(dname, S3.Pos - 1), S3.Pos - S4.Pos - 1) as SecondButLastWord,
       right(dname, S4.Pos - 1) as LastWord
from test
  cross apply (select charindex(' ', dname)) as S1(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(' ', dname, S1.Pos+1)) as S2(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(' ', reverse(dname))) as S4(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(' ', reverse(dname), S4.Pos+1)) as S3(Pos)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/515b5/1/0)**:

```
| FIRSTWORD | SECONDWORD |        WORDSINTHEMIDDLE | SECONDBUTLASTWORD | LASTWORD |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       0.1 |         ML | LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE |                10 |    MG/ML |
```

Comment: Wow!! nice use of APPLY +1 ..better than my answer

Comment: Nice indeed *(as always)* but it will only work if no other column has a variable amount of words. Far fetched but `kW h` is a valid measure and would break the statement.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, that is true. It will also break if there are drugs that does not have a value for a column. I'm actually currently looking in a drug database used in Sweden and if the data OP has to deal with is something like that he will have trouble. For instance `4 mg (grupp B)` or `25 mikrog/125 mikrog` and `60 milj ie`.

Comment: @Franklin - Do you mean that this solves your problem or is your problem solved in any other way? btw. I think you meant to thank Mikael.

Comment: sorry for late comment,does mysql have something like cross apply?

Comment: @young001 Don't think it does.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson so the only solution is like below(joe's),that's much longer than yours.

Comment: @young001 I don't know enough MySQL to answer that. You should ask a new question about how you best do this in MySQL. That would draw the attention by the guys that really know MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for split your value

```
CREATE FUNCTION Splitfunction(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(8000)       

select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @String       

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
    if len(@String) = 0 break       
end   
return      

end
```

after that use that function in your query

```
SELECT i.items FROM dbo.Splitfunction('0.1 ML LIDOCAINE HYDROCHLORIDE 10 MG/ML',' ') AS i
```

now you insert that value in your another table.

May this will help you?

Regards

Amit Vyas

Comment: hi ABVyas ,i know the above table valued function , now how can i insert the data into test1 table from test table, we cannot insert it by using table valued function and also we cannot use it in a select statement? kindly study my requirement again i.e i have to pass the records from test table to test1 table,. it is just sample only , coming to my requirement i have to pass 15 lac records in this method

Comment: Many thanks to all , finally my requiremnt is full filld with help of Joe.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use DB_Name
GO
if (object_id('splitFields') is not null)
drop function splitFields;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION splitFields(
    @strIds varchar(max) 
)
RETURNS @temp table (unit1 varchar(50),     measure1 varchar(50),drugname varchar(50),unit2 varchar(50),measure2 varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN 
    declare @i int,@j int,@l int,@v bigint;
    SET @i = 0;
    SET @j = 0;
    SET @l = len(@strIds);
    declare @unit1 varchar(50), @measure1 varchar(50),@drugname varchar(50),@unit2 varchar(50),@measure2 varchar(50);
    declare @no int;
    set @no = 0
    while (@j < @l)
    BEGIN
        SET @j = charindex(' ',@strIds,@i+1);
        IF @j = 0 set @j = @l+1;
        SET @v = substring(@strIds,@i+1,@j-@i-1);
        if @no = 0 then set @unit1= @v
        if @no = 1 then set @measure1= @v
        if @no = 2 then set @drugname= @v
        if @no = 3 then set @unit2= @v
        if @no = 4 then set @measure2= @v
        SET @no = @no + 1;
        SET @i = @j;
    END
    insert into @temp(unit1, measure1,drugname,unit2,measure2) values(@unit1, @measure1,@drugname,@unit2,@measure2)
    RETURN ;
END
GO
```

I have not enough time do test, please test it by yourself.

Comment: Hi yukaizhao , table valued function is not suitable my requirements because we are not able to use it in select statement that too i have to use to move 15 lac records from different source tables to different destination tables.

Comment: oh, you can use cursor read row by row, and insert temp table values into test1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

This query is little long, but gives you as reuired

```
select left(dname,charindex(' ',dname)) as unit1,
       substring(dname,charindex(' ',dname)+1,charindex(' ',dname,charindex(' ',dname)+1)-charindex(' ',dname)-1) as measure1,
       substring(dname,charindex(' ',dname,charindex(' ',dname)+1)+1,len(dname)-charindex(' ',reverse(dname),charindex(' ',reverse(dname))+1)-charindex(' ',dname,charindex(' ',dname)+1)+1) as drugname, 
       reverse(substring(reverse(dname),charindex(' ',reverse(dname),charindex(' ',reverse(dname))+1)-2,charindex(' ',reverse(dname),charindex(' ',reverse(dname))+1)-charindex(' ',reverse(dname))-1)) as unit2,
       reverse(left(reverse(dname),charindex(' ',reverse(dname))-1)) as measure2
from test
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/679a0/1)

Comment: Hi Joe , the above query is not splitting the string in proper format.just now i vefied , it is failed where drugname lenght is increasing or decreasing i.e unit1 measure1 drugname measure2
0.09  ML MACUGEN  MG/ML
MACUGEN  0.09 ML PEGAPTANIB  MG/ML